# Authentication with JWT using GraphQL

Tags: authentication, jwt, graphql, relay

After some search on the web I found that the best way of JWT authentication when using GraphQL is by inserting the JWT token into the GraphQL context. By doing so, resolvers can have access to it and check if the user is logged in, has permissions, etc.

I was wondering if I will need to place the authentication logic/function into every resolver that authentication is required. Is there a way which I could set by default (eg. middlewares) the authentication to every query except for login/logout/register/forgotpasword ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to do checking in resolvers. You can add a middleware in your server side.

```js
const graphQLServer = express();
graphQLServer.use('/graphql', function(req, res, next) {
  var token = req.headers.token;
  if (token != null && token != 'undefined') {
    //Do token verification here
    next();
  } else {

    // if there is no token
    // return an error
    return res.status(403).send({
      success: false,
      message: 'No token provided.'
    });
  }
})
```

Just try this

Answer (score 3):

This question pops up every so often but not enough has been discussed. I think the answer lies not in the technology but in which way best suits your needs.

It is important to be mindful when adopting GraphQL that;

- You don't have to give up on REST
- You can have **more than one** GraphQL endpoints

Here are some suggestions based on my experience with implementing GraphQL

### Authentication

For login/logout/forgot password and the whole shebang, consider going old-school. Form Post + Server-side rendering, REST API served us well for decades. Many third-party authentication services are based on this (Facebook Login, Google, OAuth2... etc). I tend to avoid using GraphQL for this purpose.

### Authorisation

The logic to check if the requester is **authorised** to access the GraphQL can be generalised to 2 levels

#### GraphQL services

Essentially you check to see if the requester is authorised to use GraphQL service. Typically it's easier to check if the requester is authenticated, else deny access to the service altogether. This is typically done via a web server middleware.

There will be times where you'll need to expose some GraphQL queries to anonymous users, and I tend to lean towards having another 'unrestricted' GraphQL endpoint. This endpoint tends to have little to no mutations, exposes a limited subset of information and restricted nested queries.

Basically, you look at the data and decide which information/operation is public and which is not. IMO this is much easier to manage and secure than have a single GraphQL endpoint and implementing authorisation checkpoints in every query path/resolver.

#### Fine grain authorisation

At this stage basically, all requesters are authenticated users. We may need to question:

- Is the requester the same user whose info is currently viewed?
- Is the requester a friend of the user whose info is currently viewed?
- Is the requester a member of the company whose info is currently viewed?

This is where putting the checking logic in resolvers (or models) really makes sense. I personally think resolvers are a great place to do this. Coupled with [DataLoader](https://github.com/facebook/dataloader) the implementation can still be fast and effective.

Hope this helps!